# how to replace null input from user to Zero in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to replace user input which is null or nothing to zero by using
 ---if("".equals(br3.readLine())).
 i am not able to do this practise.Please help me on this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class abc{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("enter the no of test cases");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("no of test cases:"+a);

        for (int j =0;j<a;j++)
        {
            System.out.println("enter for the"+(j+1)+" case");
            System.out.println("enter the no of tress");
            BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int b=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("no of tress:"+b);
            int[] ar=new int[b];
            for (int i =0;i<b;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("enter the plucks for tree:"+i);
                BufferedReader br3=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                if("".equals(br3.readLine()))
                {
                    ar[i]=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    ar[i]=Integer.parseInt(br3.readLine());
                }
            }
            System.out.println("hello");
            for (int i =b-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                System.out.println(ar[i]+"\t");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what are you getting? What are you expecting?

Comment: i am expecting like if user doesn't provide any input then that thing should be replaced by 0 in ouput .

Answer (score 2):

`if("".equals(br3.readLine()))` is not enough, since readLine may return null.

Try :

```
String line = br3.readLine();
if(line == null || line.equals(""))
```

or

```
String line = br3.readLine();
if(line == null || line.isEmpty())
```

Comment: You can use `line.isEmpty()` instead of `line.equals("")` (better performance, as it will just check if length is 0 instead of comparing strings).

Comment: @FlorentBayle Thanks for the comment. `isEmpty` would probably be a bit faster, though not by much, since comparing to an empty String means that you don't need to iterate over the other String (since either both empty, or their lengths don't match and you can return false).

Comment: @ Bayle and Eran ..thanks ...String line = br3.readLine();
if (line!=null && (line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().length() <= 0))..this works for me..and it is logical too but clarify me on one thing we are checking line!=null. but we are already expecting it is to be null.

Comment: @MohitDarmwal I'm not sure I understand the question. You must make sure that `line != null` before doing anything else with the `line` variable, in order to avoid `NullPointerException`. In your suggested code you check that line is a not-null empty String. If it's null, your condition will return false and you might assume (by mistake) that the String is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. you did a typo in line number 16.

```
BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int b=Integer.parseInt(br1.readLine());
```